# Debug Error - Eigen Library Visual Studio RunTime Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, eigen

I write a couple of functions by using Eigen Library on Eclipse, build, run and test all my functions correctly, there is not any error on Eclipse (MinGW compiler). But then I realize that I have to use Visual Studio compiler, and try to compile the code on Visual Studio 2010. Even though there is not any error during buildtime, the code does not work in runtime, and get the error as shown in the link. I will be pleasure if someone helps me about this problem ?? 
  [Invalid sizes when resizing a matrix or an array - error Visual Studio 2010 compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ7iK.png)

Comment: Share some relevant code. It is impossible to figure out what's wrong if you don't provide a single bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I solved the problem :) The error is about the size of the input file. I read the wrong file so there is an imcompatibility between what I expect to read and the real file.

In addition to this, to build with Visual_Studio I changed some properties of Visual Studio as explained in eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=IDEs#Visual_Studio. It may help to whom try to migrate code from mingw to visual studio compiler.